getting error while launching laravel 10 project. Even any artisan command is not working
The exact error is :
PS C:\Users\Shubham\Documents\GitHub\orange-mlm> php artisan serve

In UrlGenerator.php line 128:

  Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct(): Argument #2 ($request) must be of type Illuminate\Http\Reques  
  t, null given, called in C:\Users\Shubham\Documents\GitHub\orange-mlm\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate  
  \Routing\RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 64


I working on my project so long and when i restart my project i got this error.

I got that error message because I used asset() in config folder. Try not to use any url() or asset() in the config folder mainly in app.php.
